# holiday from Munich

Tags: germany, italy

We are visiting family near Munich. We would like to have a six day holiday, but we don't know where to go from Munich.

We like smaller beautiful towns rather than big cities. Towns with quaint streets, cafes, museums. Towns that are walkable. Ideally we don't want to drive, so they should be accessible by rail.

By default, we're thinking of flying to Venice and Florence. Yes, these are larger cities, but since we aren't familiar with smaller towns, we've been picking larger, known cities. We're thinking Germany or Italy.

Any suggestions where we might go?

Thanks for your help

GT

Comment: Sorry, but an answer to your question or preference would be primarly opinion based. There is an almost endless list of smaller town near Munich, which all fit your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you would fly to Venice, then most of Germany is within range. The Rhine. Berlin. The North Sea coast.

You can reach the Alps. Hike up mountains in view of the really steep peaks.

[Rothenburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rothenburg_ob_der_Tauber), but depending on the season you might meet many other tourists. (Attention, there are several towns with this name.)

[Neuschwanstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuschwanstein_Castle).

You might also look for a "genuine" little German town, but those have few interesting museums.